# Android - how to test if the correct fragment is loaded?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-fragments, android-activity

I recently started coding my first android project using Android Studio 3.1.2 and SDK 19.

Currently I'm writing the tests for my no-UI objects and want to test, which fragment an activity loads in the `oncreate()` method. The activity itself inspects the Intent that invoked itself and, depending on a flag inside the Intent a different Fragment shall be loaded. The Activity layout only contains a FrameLayout named `fragment_container`.

SplashActivity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        if (!(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isLaunch", true))) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new LoginFragment()).commit();
        } else {
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SplashFragment()).commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's in fact all the code of `SplashActivity` at the moment. 
Now my question is, if there's any way to inspect, which Fragment has been loaded? Possibly `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragmentByTag()`? Thanks in forward.

**EDIT:**

According to the suggested solution by @rxabin I added an `instanceof` check in my test methods.

SplashActivityTest:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SplashActivityTest {

    private final SplashActivity testActivity = new SplashActivity();
    private final Intent testIntent = new Intent();

    @Test
    public void canLoadSplashFragment() {
        testActivity.recreate();
        Fragment fragment = testActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        assertTrue(fragment instanceof SplashFragment);
    }

    @Test
    public void canLoadLoginFragment() {
        testIntent.putExtra("isLaunch", false);
        testActivity.recreate();
        Fragment fragment = testActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        assertTrue(fragment instanceof LoginFragment);
    }

}
```

When I try to run this test, I get a RuntimeException: `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` referring to the line where I define `testActivity`. Any idea how I have to instantiate an activity, so I can call `testActivity.recreate()` on it?

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences

Comment: if u r just debugging, you can use toasts

Comment: This is not helping me a lot, tho i don't get, how toasts or SharedPreferences help me identifying the fragment, that's replacing `fragment_container` ...

Comment: You should follow the recommendation by Google and add the listeners to the fragment onAttached. That way, you can know which fragment is attached to the activity. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#EventCallbacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `FragmentManager`'s `findFragmentById()` method, then you can check which fragment it is by using `instanceof`.

Your code should look something like this:

```
mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();    
Fragment frag = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
if (frag instanceof LoginFragment) {
   // It's a LoginFragment
} else {
    // It's something else!
}
```

Comment: Have you noticed, that I always create a new anonymous Fragment? Will this solution also work then?

Comment: @Procra by anonymous do you mean that the fragment may be of any class? By using findFragmentById() you'll be getting the fragment that's loaded into the container, after that you can check if your fragment is the "correct" one.

Comment: @Procra This is definitely a threading problem. You're not able to create an activity from a worker thread so you're getting that error. Try using an ActivityTestRule (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule). Hopefully this fixes your poblem